# CSS and z-index: child element under parent element in a list

Tags: css, list, menu, z-index

I am working on a layout for a webshop and am experiencing a problem which seems to be very specific.

There is a dropdown navigation which is design to look kind of a tab with a box under it. The point is, that there is a 1px border line between the tab (first level Menu Item) and the box (second level items) which I can't hide.

I thought about giving the second level box a lower z-index than the first level element, but that didn't changed anything. I read a lot about z-index, how it works and how it NOT works, but nothing was about z-index within one list.

This is how it should looks like and how it really looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbQ6x.png

I created a codepen, which shows the problem very good, when hovering the first level items: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNqJxN

```
li .dropdown{
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            padding:0;
            margin: 0 0 0 -1px; /*Putting a negativ margin-top here puts the box OVER the parent element :-( */
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid $light-grey;
            width: 280px;
            height: 200px;
            &.right {
                right: -1px;
                left: auto;
            }
            .dropdown-1-2 {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solve this issue with z-index to have the bottom of the li to overlap the top of the dropdown.

In your case, I had to remove the * selector for the z-index which came after the li and dropdown which was resetting the z-index to 2 on everything in that navigation. Instead I created just the one stacking context ([here's an article on it](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)) for the first nav to appear above the second, and then I gave the ul position relative and the dropdown a z-index of -1 and -1px top margin to move it just behind the unpositioned li.

```
#mainnav {
    ...

    ul {
        @include reduced-list;
        ...
        position: relative;

        li .dropdown{
            ...
            margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
            z-index: -1;

            ...

        &#nav1 {
            z-index: 2;
        }
        &#nav2 {
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

Sorry, the codepen didn't save.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it adding a pseudo element to cover the border

```
li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
  }
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwWLwW)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much!

Both answers solved my problem like a charme!

I created a codepen with the solution here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPpQOq

```
ul {
        @include reduced-list;
        position: relative; /* YEAH */
        float:right;
        li .dropdown{
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            padding:0;
            margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; /* YEAH */
            z-index: -1; /* YEAH */
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid $light-grey;
            width: 280px;
            height: 200px;
            &.right {
                right: -1px;
                left: auto;
            }
        }
```

Placing a nested child under a parent element seems to be possible :-)